# own goal from cross

Tags: football

I was playing FIFA, and Bale crossed it in, from where an opposing player tried heading it out, but knocked it into his own goal. The goal was given to Bale. Was that an own goal, or was the game right in giving the goal to Bale?

Comment: Was the ball going in anyway without the defender's touch?

Comment: no. it came in and if no one had hit it, it would have gone out toward the other wing. https://postimg.org/image/qnkcgwqgf/

Comment: Probably a computer error, then. Note that people have reported events where a GLT screen showed the ball clearly not a goal/clearly a goal, with either (or both of) the commentary track and the scoreline being the opposite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a computer game, not the real sport.

Comment: It's about a game about the game... what's the problem?

Comment: You should better ask on Arqade.SE, which is the appropriate venue for questions about video games of any kind. This is a venue for sports questions. Had you asked what rules apply in real-world games, this would be acceptable (and I believe such a question already exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on current Laws of the Game, there's no official guidance for declaring what constitutes an own goal; that is, declaring the scorer of a goal (regardless of whether it's an attacker or defender) is not part of the "official" rules.

That said, most current leagues rely on the following guideline:

> If the ball was struck by an attacker and was headed **towards** the goal before a defender intervened, then the attacker is credited with the goal.  If the ball was headed wide, or high, or anywhere else not on target after the last attacker touched it, then was touched by a defender or the goalie and went in, it's considered an own goal.

This can be a bit silly, of course.  You've probably seen, for example, free kicks that—while indeed on target—were going to be easily saved by the keeper before they took a deflection and wound up in the goal.  The attacker gets credit for the goal because the initial shot was on target.

And this means that cruelly, a keeper can be credited with an own goal if a ball hits the woodwork and is headed out, then hits the keeper and goes in.

The English Premier League even has a [Dubious Goals Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubious_Goals_Committee) to rule on goals where the official scorer is in doubt.  This obviously has no effect on the most important fact: the final score of the game, but it *is* used to keep consistent statistics.

---

In your case, it sounds like a classic own goal, unless Bale's original cross was headed towards the goal anyway.  Sounds like the game made a scoring error.

Comment: It's a very nice answer. You mentioned "Based on current Laws of the Game, there's no official guidance for declaring what constitutes an own goal". I can understand that. But should there be a guideline or instruction on this? I can't find it on the internet.